# OSX 10.9 - Mavericks webdav client lock issue

Tags: macos, locking, webdav, osx-mavericks

I have a webdav server implementation that works fine with windows and OSX 10.8 versions. Since OS X 10.9 upgrade, many webdav actions including dragging a file onto a webdav mount using Finder and editing files using MS office applications (Microsoft Word, Office, Powerpoint) have stopped working.

Looking at client <-> webdav server traffic, it appears that after acquiring LOCK on a file, client is not supplying lock token in subsequent requests to server, resulting in 423 responses on subsequent operations. According to webdav spec, client needs to supply file lock-token in subsequent commands to server.

I confirmed that this is not a problem with 10.8 or earlier versions.

File drag and drop to Finder webdav mount show following sequence of request and responses:

```
PROPFIND /webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx 404
PROPFIND /webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx
PUT /egnyte-internal/webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx 201
PROPFIND /webdav/Private/a123/._test.pptx 404
LOCK /webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx 200
UNLOCK /webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx 204
PROPFIND /webdav/Private/a123/._test.pptx 404
LOCK /webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx 200
UNLOCK /webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx 423
```

Looking at wireshark output for this sequence, second unlock request doesn't include the Lock-Token header. At this point, system.log shows error "unexpected statusCode 423" and mount disconnects.

Here is the UNLOCK request headers, missing Lock-Token:

```
UNLOCK /webdav/Private/a123/test.pptx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10001
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic YWRtaTeyhsbaksVusjhs9tZTEyMw==
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: WebDAVFS/3.0.0 (03008000) Darwin/13.0.0 (x86_64)
\r\n
```

Has anyone else seen this problem and have a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I think that's the same issue as this: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23525832
I'm having the same problem, but no solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

I must say I have not encountered the problem myself, but I was looking around for a problem that we are experiencing with our WebDAV server. On the way I found this:
The description of your problem sounds quite similar to what I was reading in these posts. Have a look and report if that helps you. Seems quite a lot of WebDAV servers are broken.

[http://www.engadget.com/discuss/](http://www.engadget.com/discuss/tip-problems-remotely-connecting-to-your-synology-nas-in-os-x-mavericks-here-s-how-to-fix-1kzw/)

and this:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5476839

At the very least this is a very good starting point.